# Making it mendatory to get email with facebook oAuth with Socialite

Tags: facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am trying to use facebook oAuth for my users to login/register to my website. For this, i require user's email address

Facebook oAuth dialog has option to provide / not provide email but even if the user's doesn't provide their email, I cannot re-request authorization from facebook again as it considers the user as logged in and simply redirects to call back url.

I am using Laravel and Socialite package.

Any solutions??

Comment: Be aware that not all users on Facebook has an email.

Comment: how do they login? phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socialite allows you to get user information directly after the successful authorization by using

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
$user->email;
```

I would expect `$user->email` to contain the users email address if he accepted to share her with the app and to be empty if the user denied the email address sharing.
And if `$user->email` is empty throw an error and ask the user to re-authorize. If it's not working you could try to de-authroize the user, a guide can be found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/socialite-logout).

---

A convenient way to avoid any issues is to display a warning that the user should allow email sharing if he wants to log in with Facebook.